# Improve performance of postgresql query

Tags: sql, postgresql, optimization

I have problem with one of queries in my program. I have 2 tables: data_all_de and employers_de. In general i have same situation for 10 countries, but takes 'DE' for example.

**data_all_de** have 31 columns, no indexes and 1 primary key - id (int). This table have something about 2M records, but records which meet conditions of query is about 505K.

employers_de have 3 columns (id int, employer_name varchar(255), variations varchar[](255) - array, no primary key, no indexes. Here I have 44K records.

My query looks:

```
UPDATE data_all_de
SET company_ok = (SELECT name 
                    FROM employers_de
                    WHERE employer_name = ANY(variations) LIMIT 1)
WHERE data_all_de.employer_name is not null 
AND data_all_de.company_ok is null 
AND data_all_de.row_status = 'N';"""
```

It's tooking from 40 minutes to 60 minutes dependly on country. I try analize them with EXPLAIN so this is output for DE:

```
    "Update on data_all_de  (cost=0.00..3377618.96 rows=627019 width=1642)"
    "  ->  Seq Scan on data_all_de  (cost=0.00..3377618.96 rows=627019 width=1642)"
    "        Filter: ((employer_name IS NOT NULL) AND (company_ok IS NULL) AND (row_status = 'N'::bpchar))"
    "        SubPlan 1"
    "          ->  Limit  (cost=0.00..0.78 rows=1 width=25)"
    "                ->  Seq Scan on employers_de  (cost=0.00..908.06 rows=1169 width=25)"
    "                      Filter: (data_all_de.employer_name = ANY ((variations)::text[]))"
    "JIT:"
    "  Functions: 11"
    "  Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true"
```

How I can improve this? Using index? Split this query into 2 smaller and use a 'temp' table?

In general, data in employers_de is constant, but data in data_all_de is changing every day and this query is executed every day after inserting new data into table.

Also, this query running for 10 countries (10 pairs of data_all_xx + employers_xx) in similar time.

I would be grateful for the tips.

Comment: Your probably is probably the `employer_name = ANY(variations)`.  I think you would need to fix the data model to make this more efficient -- that is, array references are rather trickier to optimize using indexes.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest fixing the structure of `employers_de` so you are not using array ops:

```
create table employers_de_normalized as
    select e.employee_name, u.variation
    from employers_de e cross join lateral
         unnest(de.variations) u(variation);

create index idx_employers_de_normalized_variation on employers_de_normalized(variation);
```

And then write the `set` part of the query as:

```
SET company_ok = (SELECT edn.employer_name 
                  FROM employers_de_normalized edn
                  WHERE de.employer_name = edn.variation
                  LIMIT 1
                 )
```

This should use the index and be much faster.  Note that the `LIMIT 1` still seems problematic to me.  You can fix that by using `DISTINCT ON` when you create the temporary table, so `variation` is unique in the table.

Comment: Why the cost on query plan now is higher than before? I created table 'employers_de_normalized' with your SQL and replace my previous SET with 'SET company_ok = (SELECT edn.name FROM employers_de_normalized edn WHERE data_all_de.employer_name = edn.variation LIMIT 1)' but now I get "Update on data_all_de  (cost=0.00..526137913.71 rows=627019 width=1642)". I understand your idea with pairs 1:1 instead of array (new table), but this result of explain is very misunderstanding to me... With 'distinct on' on SET I get 'Update on data_all_de  (cost=0.00..526148886.55 rows=627019 width=1642)'

Comment: @Bob . . . Did you create the specified index?

Comment: Ohh, I forgot - sorry for this stupid mistake. I created now and I get 'Update on data_all_de  (cost=0.00..8188868.76 rows=627019 width=1642)' with distinct on. Why this cost is higher than my original version?

Comment: @Bob . . . The plan in your version says that `employer_de` has 1,169 rows.  But your question says 44k.  That might have something to do with the difference in estimates.

Comment: I post 44k because it's depends on different country and this is average. In DE case I checked right now and I have 23.914 rows in employers_de and 36.280 in employers_de_normalized. You have idea why on EXPLAIN I get 1.169 rows when the real number of rows is extremely different?

Comment: @Bob . . . The statistics might be out of date.  You may need to analyze the table.